# Alembic Django Flask migrate database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a database shared between django and flask.

In flask app, I use sqlAlchemy and use Alembic to migrate database.
But when I migrate database and use command:

$ alembic revision --autogenerate -m "some message"

It will automatically remove all tables that django had created:

```
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected removed table u'django_content_type'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected removed table u'auth_group'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected removed table u'auth_user'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected removed table u'auth_user_groups'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected removed table u'django_session'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected removed table u'auth_permission'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected removed table u'auth_user_user_permissions'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected removed table u'account_userprofile'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected removed table u'south_migrationhistory'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected removed table u'django_site'
```

How to configure Alembic so that database migration does not remove tables of django?

Comment: Does Alembic or Flask have db introspection tools (like django has)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem by my self:

In env file, function:

```
def run_migrations_online():
    target_metadata.reflect(engine, only=[ "django_content_type", "auth_group", ...])
```

Put your tables here. This define with engine that the tables were existed and do not drop them.

Comment: thanks I also solved my problem like this. but how about the the alembix tables? I got them detected by autogenerate

Answer (score 1):

You can use `include_object` from the environment context. The function can return `True` or `False`, indicating if the given table/object should be considered in the autogenerate sweep

See here for more details: [Alembic API](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html?highlight=alembic%20environment#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext)